# Knitr emptyline after \include graphics

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have a little question, I'm not sure of the cause, but the  following  knitr code :

```
<<toto, echo=FALSE, comment=NA, results='asis'>>=
  #Data
     a<- c(1:100)
     b<- c(100:200)
  #Plot1
    plot(a)
  #Plot2
    plot(b)
@
```

produce this LaTeX code :

```
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/toto1}
  (empty line here)
\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/toto2}
  (empty line here)
```

How can I remove this empty line?

Answer (score 6):

Use the chunk option `fig.show='hold'`.